# GET API call works in browser but not in Postman and HttpClient C#

Tags: c#, api, postman

This is the url: https://thongtindoanhnghiep.co/api/company/3901212654

[image: This is the request header]

The curl used to import to Postman:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://thongtindoanhnghiep.co/api/company/3901212654' \
--header 'sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"' \
--header 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
--header 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
--header 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36' \
--header 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
--header 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' \
--header 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
--header 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
--header 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document'
```

And the code in C#

```
// Create client to get API from thongtindoanhnghiep
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

// Get company info
var stringTask = client.GetStringAsync("https://thongtindoanhnghiep.co/api/company/3901212654");
var msg = await stringTask;
var parsedCompany = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CompanyDto.ParseFromApi>(msg);
```

Neither Postman nor C# HttpClient works.
The Postman will throw the "COULD NOT SEND REQUEST" and HttpClient will throw "No such host is known". **But the browser works fine**.

Can someone help me please?

**Updated:**
It seems to be a network error or because of the ISP. I changed to another network with different ISP and it works fine. I will check my network setting later. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you looked in chrome tools->network tab and compared the call being made to what postman is sending?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you're doing in postman? I've just done a GET request to that URL in postman and it returned the data as expected.

Comment: I tryed in Postman too , everythin works fine.  And it returns data using httpClient too.

Comment: Check your proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use get() or getAsync().

**For GET Method**

```
           var URL = https://thongtindoanhnghiep.co/api/company/3901212654";
           HttpClient clients = new HttpClient();
           clients.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
           clients.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
           new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = clients.GetAsync(URL).Result;
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            var res= "";
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
```

**For POST Method**  ( Using Resharper )

```
var URL = https://thongtindoanhnghiep.co/api/company/3901212654";
var rootobject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object); 
//object to string
var dataObject = "";

var client = new RestClient(URL);
var request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = Method.POST;
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.Parameters.Clear();
request.AddParameter("application/json", rootobject, ParameterType.RequestBody);

var response = client.Execute(request);
if (response.IsSuccessful)
    {
       dataObject = response.Content; // raw content as string  
    }
```

If HttpClient won't work use WebClient